# How to modify the message in "when and otherwise" function in spark datafarme in scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have dataframe where I'm doing some conditional check with it and creating a column name like valRow and maintaining their status on it. I'm also trying to display message into console, here I'm able to display the message into console successfully. I got stuck with two things

1) I wanted to display the uniqueID of the false result in otherwise function which in highlighted bold letter below, right now in the log it display their name like uniqueID as it is.

```
.otherwise(getFlagStatus(false.booleanValue(),"valRow","JKM record -- ITC_SALE_TYPE cannot be empty ", childDF("uniqueID").toString))
```

2) I wanted the count of a false result.

```
childDF=
+--------+-------------+-------------+---------+
|uniqueID|HACKER_K_TYPE|ITC_SALE_TYPE|OPERATOR |
+--------+-------------+-------------+---------+        
|    2568|            F|            3|      S  |
|    2569|            F|            1|      S  |
|    2570|            F|            1|      C  |
|    2571|            F|             |      S  |
|    2572|            F|            3|      S  |
|    2572|            F|            3|      S  | 
|    2574|            F|             |      C  | 
+--------+-------------+-------------+---------+


Dataframe creates in runtime.
    +--------+-------------+-------------+---------+---------+
    |uniqueID|HACKER_K_TYPE|ITC_SALE_TYPE|OPERATOR |valRow   |
    +--------+-------------+-------------+---------+---------+        
    |    2568|            F|            3|      S  |  true   |
    |    2569|            F|            1|      S  |  true   |
    |    2570|            F|            1|      C  |  true   |
    |    2571|            F|            1|      S  |  false  |
    |    2572|            F|            3|      S  |  true   |
    |    2573|            F|            3|      S  |  true   |
    |    2574|            F|            3|      C  |  false  |
    +--------+-------------+-------------+---------+---------+

def getFlagStatus(flagValue:Boolean,functionName:String,message:String,uniqueID:String) :Boolean =  {



        if(flagValue.equals(false)) {
          ValidationMap.put(ValidationStatus,false)
          logger.mdLog(LogTypeError, functionName, Map(
            Message -> message,
            idNumber->uniqueID
          ))

        }
        false
      }



val newChildDF2 =childD              
 .withColumn("valRow",when(childDF("ITC_SALE_TYPE") =!= " " && childDF("ITC_SALE_TYPE") =!= Nil.toString(),lit(true))
              .otherwise(getFlagStatus(false.booleanValue(),"valRow","JKM record -- ITC_SALE_TYPE cannot be empty ",childDF("uniqueID").toString)))
              .drop("valRow")
```

My English is not so much good if anybody faces any problem with it please leave your message,any help will be appricated.

Answer (score 0):

Your method looks complicated. You can do it simple as below.

What I would suggest is to use `when` function as below

```
val newChildDF2 =childDF
  .withColumn("valRow",when(childDF("ITC_SALE_TYPE") =!= " " && childDF("ITC_SALE_TYPE") =!= Nil.toString(),lit(true))
    .otherwise(false))
```

You already have the `dataframe`

```
+--------+-------------+-------------+--------+------+
|uniqueID|HACKER_K_TYPE|ITC_SALE_TYPE|OPERATOR|valRow|
+--------+-------------+-------------+--------+------+
|2568    |F            |3            |S       |true  |
|2569    |F            |1            |S       |true  |
|2570    |F            |1            |C       |true  |
|2571    |F            |             |S       |false |
|2572    |F            |3            |S       |true  |
|2572    |F            |3            |S       |true  |
|2574    |F            |             |C       |false |
+--------+-------------+-------------+--------+------+
```

Now you can just use `filter` function to get the `dataframe` which has `false` in `valRow` as

```
val tempDF = newChildDF2.filter($"valRow"===false)
```

`dataframe` would be

```
+--------+-------------+-------------+--------+------+
|uniqueID|HACKER_K_TYPE|ITC_SALE_TYPE|OPERATOR|valRow|
+--------+-------------+-------------+--------+------+
|2571    |F            |             |S       |false |
|2574    |F            |             |C       |false |
+--------+-------------+-------------+--------+------+
```

Now to print the `uniqueID` in the console you can convert to `rdd` and use `println` as

```
tempDF.select("uniqueID").rdd.foreach(println)
```

Output would be

```
[2571]
[2574]
```

**You can even save them to files**

You can save `rdd` to text tiles as

```
tempDF.select("uniqueID").rdd.saveAsTextFile("path to output file")
```

You can even save the `dataframe` as `csv` too as

```
tempDF.write.format("csv").save("path to output file")
```

I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: thanks for your reply, Basically I have huge code from that huge code I took selected code where I'm facing the issue, you can see in the `otherwise` I'm calling user define method(my own method(getFlagStatus)) if the condition is failed then message will log into logger(log4j) with line number(uniqueID) but I'm not able to log the uniqueID into logger.

Comment: then you should update your question with what are ValidationMap,  ValidationStatus, LogTypeError, functionName, Message and idNumber. But still I would like to consider my approach too.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think what you want to achieve can be done with 'otherwise'. However, I have managed to get it working using a UDF:

```
val df = Seq(  
  (2568, false, "3", "S"),
  (2569, false, "1", "S"),
  (2570, false, "1", "C"),
  (2571, false, "", "S"),
  (2572, false, "3", "S"),
  (2572, false, "3", "S"),
  (2574, false, "", "C")
).toDF("uniqueID", "HACKER_K_TYPE", "ITC_SALE_TYPE", "OPERATOR")

val logResults = udf((saleType: String, uniqueID: String) => {
  var res = true
  if(saleType == "") {
    println("logging unique id here:" + uniqueID)
    res = false
  }
  res
})

val newdf = df.withColumn("valRow",logResults($"ITC_SALE_TYPE", $"uniqueID"))

newdf.show()
```

Output:

```
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [uniqueID: int, HACKER_K_TYPE: boolean ... 2 more fields]
logResults: org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction = UserDefinedFunction(<function2>,BooleanType,Some(List(StringType, StringType)))
newdf: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [uniqueID: int, HACKER_K_TYPE: boolean ... 3 more fields]
logging unique id here:2571
logging unique id here:2574
+--------+-------------+-------------+--------+------+
|uniqueID|HACKER_K_TYPE|ITC_SALE_TYPE|OPERATOR|valRow|
+--------+-------------+-------------+--------+------+
|    2568|        false|            3|       S|  true|
|    2569|        false|            1|       S|  true|
|    2570|        false|            1|       C|  true|
|    2571|        false|             |       S| false|
|    2572|        false|            3|       S|  true|
|    2572|        false|            3|       S|  true|
|    2574|        false|             |       C| false|
+--------+-------------+-------------+--------+------+
```